# Streaming webcam and static video from Ubuntu in h.264 over RTP/RTSP

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg

What setup can be used to stream video from Ubuntu?

I'd like to find something that would

1. Use my laptop webcam to produce a stream a H.264 IP-camera working over RTP/RTSP would produce.
2. Produce a similar stream from a static video file saved on disk.

`gstreamer` with its powerful `ffmpeg` plugin seems to be the tool to work with streaming on Ubuntu. How can I use them for my purpose? Maybe there are other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at [vlc / videolan](http://www.videolan.org/). it can stream data both from files and from camera / digitizer. as bonus you can handle not only multiple unicast connections, but also generate multicast streams.

Comment: @pQd, Thanks, I'm now diving into VLC, do you know any good tutorials on streaming from VLC?

Comment: @Alex - take a look at vlc tutorial: http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/index.html or just google. vlc has quite lively forum: http://forum.videolan.org/ - you might find plenty of answers there.